# IME options are missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, ime

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. When I go to keyboard options for some languages (Simplified Chinese, Japanese, etc.), I see only some nameless keyboards, and it doesn't let me choose the MS Wubi, MS Pinyin or MS IME. Does anyone have any suggestion?